# Tensorflow error can't figure out what it is

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I was doing tensorflow object detection project to detect sign languages using google colab
I was getting tensorflow has no attribute gflie error and I found that i have to downgrade to tensorflow 1
so I ran `!pip install tensorflow==1.13.0rc1` in my colab cell
But now when I run the same cell I get this error which I cant figureout how to resolve
code -

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + 'generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + 'train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + 'label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + 'train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + 'generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + 'test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + 'label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + 'test.record'}
```

Error -

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 61, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got item {
  name: "Hello"
  id: 1
}
item {
  name: "Yes"
  id: 2
}
item {
  name: "Thank You"
  id: 3
}
item {
  name: "I Love You"
  id: 5
}
item {
  name: "No"
  id: 5
}

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 61, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got item {
  name: "Hello"
  id: 1
}
item {
  name: "Yes"
  id: 2
}
item {
  name: "Thank You"
  id: 3
}
item {
  name: "I Love You"
  id: 5
}
item {
  name: "No"
  id: 5
}
```

Other cells of my colab file

```
WORKSPACE_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace/'
SCRIPTS_PATH = 'Tensorflow/scripts/'
APIMODEL_PATH = 'Tensorflow/models/'
ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'annotations/'
IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'images/'
MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'models/'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'pre-trained-models/'
CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config'
CHECKPOINT_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'my_ssd_mobnet/'
```

```
labels = [
  {'name':'Hello', 'id':1},
  {'name':'Yes', 'id':2},
  {'name':'Thank You', 'id':3},
  {'name':'I Love You', 'id':5},
  {'name':'No', 'id':5}
]

with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + 'label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `generate_tfrecords.py`, remove line 61 and change line 62 to `label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(args.labels_path)` and if you have any line that says `fine_tune_checkpoint_version` in the `pipeline.config` file, delete that and try